# Analytic perturbation of eigenfunctions

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory

Consider a domain $\Omega_0 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and deformations of $\Omega_0$, called $\Omega_t$, obtained by a one-to-one mapping $x \mapsto x + t\varphi (x)$, where $\varphi$ is smooth. It is known that the Dirichlet and Neumann eigenvalues of the Laplacian on $\Omega_t$ vary real analytically with respect to $t$ near $t = 0$. My question is: do the eigenfunctions vary real analytically as well? Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: This is true whenever eigenvalues are simple. Reference: Kato, Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy I cannot find this in Kato. Could you please mention the page/theorem number? Thanks! Also, eigenvalues will probably be generically simple anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [recent paper](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/DC-perturb.pdf) for answers to this and similar questions. You have to translate the parameter dependence of the domain to the parameter dependence of the operator first.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, once we translate the parameter dependence of the domain to the parameter dependence of the operator, we would want to prove that if $H_t$ represents the Hilbert space of ($t$-dependent) Dirichlet/Neumann $L^2$ functions, we have to prove the existence of a unitary operator $U_t : H_t \to H_0$, such that $U_t$ is real analytic. We would also have to prove that eigenvlaues and eigenprojections vary analytically, which is already proved in Kato. I will be very grateful if you can verify that I understand this correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. And $U_t$ is just induced by the diffeomorphism $\Omega_t to \Omega_0$ which you described. For Dirichlet it is clear, for Neumann one has to think a little.