# Do Laplace-Beltrami eigenfunctions vary continuously with the metric?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

I'm interested in Laplace Beltrami operators $$-\Delta_g:\ \   D(-\Delta_g) \longrightarrow L^2\left(M,\sqrt{|g|}dx\right)$$
on a smooth compact Riemannian Manifold (M,g). Let us fix a unique metric $g$ on $M$. 
For any other smooth metric $\widetilde g$ on $M$, we can identify the square integrable functions with respect to its associated volume form with our original $L^2$ above, via the unitary map
$U:f\longmapsto \sqrt{|g|/|\widetilde g|}f.$
Under this unitary identification the Laplace-Beltrami operators corresponding to the various smooth metrics on $M$ yield a family of operators on a common domain of definition.
It has been [proved](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/tohoku-mathematical-journal/volume-35/issue-2/Generic-properties-of-the-eigenvalue-of-the-Laplacian-for-compact/10.2748/tmj/1178229047.full) that the eigenvalues of this family depend continuously on the metrics.

Is this true for the eigenfunctions or eigenprojections as well?

I feel like the answer should be yes, arguing in coordinates that if the coefficients of the operators are close, their resolvents and hence their spectral projections are, but I am not sure how to prove it rigorously.
I know that if I consider an analytic one parameter family of metrics the result holds essentially by Kato's perturbation theory.
But I am ultimately interested in proving that a certain composition of maps from functions on the manifold to $\mathbb R$  is robust to arbitrary, small (in the $C^\infty$-topology) changes in the metric and one of the maps in the composition is an operator of the form $f(-\Delta_g)$.

This is my first question here and also a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246996/do-laplace-beltrami-eigenfunctions-vary-continuously-with-the-metric) question on stackexchange, so if I'm transgressing against any etiquette rules, please do let me know. :)

Comment: For eigenfunctions: wouldn't you get problems with eigenvalues with multiplicity, similarly to the finite dimensional cases?

Comment: Imagine your manifold being a round sphere, and your continuous family of deformations being, for $s > 0$ deforming the sphere to an ellipsoid with principal axes aligned with the standard coordinate axis, and $s < 0$ the same ellipsoidal deformation but rotated so that none of the principal axes line up with the standard ones. I find it hard to believe in this case the eigenfunctions can be chosen continuously.

Comment: In the case that two eigenbranches cross, is the question, "does there exist a continuous path from one branch to at least one other," or is the question, "does there exist a continuous path from one branch to *all* the others"?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198432/analytic-perturbation-of-eigenfunctions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED: Added clarification, as pointed out by @TerryTao.

Let $g_1$, $g_2$ be Riemannian metrics and $\Delta_1$, $\Delta_2$ their respective Laplacians. Let $\lambda_1$ be an eigenvalue of $\Delta_1$ and $\lambda_2$ an eigenvalue of $\Delta_2$.

I think what can be proved is the following: Given an eigenfunction $u_2$ of $\Delta_2$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_2$, there exists an eigenfunction $u_1$ of $\Delta_1$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ such that
$$ \|u_2-u_1\|_2 \le C(|\lambda_2-\lambda_1| + \|g_2-g_1\|_{2,2})\|u_2\|_2, $$
where $C$ depends on both $g_1$ and $\lambda_1$ (specifically, the spectral gap between $\lambda_1$ and the other eigenvalues of $\Delta_1$), $\|\cdot\|_{2,2}$ is the $W^{2,2}$ Sobolev norm with respect to a background metric $g_0$, and $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the $L^2$ norm with respect to $dV_1$.

Here's a sketch of my proof:

Let $\lambda_2$ be an eigenvalue of $\Delta_2$ and $u_2$ a nontrival eigenfunction. Let $\lambda_1$ be an eigenvalue of $\Delta_1$ and $u_1$ a nontrival eigenfunction.

A straighforward calculation shows that
$$
  (-\Delta_1+\lambda_1)(u_2-u_1)
  = (\Delta_2-\Delta_1)u_2 - (\lambda_2-\lambda_1)u_2.
$$
Choose $u_1$ so that, for any eigenfunction $u$ of $\Delta_1$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_1$,
$$ \int u(u_2-u_1)\,dV_1 = 0. $$
The claim now follows by elliptic estimates.

Comment: The constant $C$ here will also depend on the invertibility of $-\Delta_1 + \lambda_1$ on the orthogonal complement of the kernel, hence depends on the spectral gap between $\lambda_1$ and the other eigenvalues of $-\Delta_1$.  This is necessary, since if there were two eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda'_1$ of $-\Delta_1$ close to $\lambda_2$ then your estimate would also imply that a $\lambda_1$-eigenfunction is close to a $\lambda'_1$-eigenfunction, contradicting orthogonality.

Comment: @TerryTao, yes. When I said $C$ depends on $g_1$, I did have the reciprocal of the spectral gap in mind. But I see that I should say that $C$ depends on $g_1$ *and* $\lambda_1$.